# Run some calculation and then update data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

Here is a very simple store method of a product controller. I do some calculation and then store the data into the database. But while updating data I have to run this calculations again and then have to save the data.

I tried several ways but I get nothing but error messages as I'm new in Laravel. How can I write the proper update method?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //vat and profit calculations
        $vat           = $request->vat;
        $buying_price  = $request->buying_price;
        $selling_price = $request->selling_price;
        $total_price   = $buying_price+($buying_price*$vat/100);
        $profit        = $selling_price-$total_price;

        $product = Products::create([
            'product_name'          => $request->product_name,
            'buying_price'          => $request->buying_price,
            'selling_price'         => $request->selling_price,
            'vat'                   => $request->vat,
            'total_price'           => $total_price,
            'profit'                => $profit,
            ]);
        return redirect("Product/{$product->id}");
       }
```

Update method (which is not working as I expect):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        $vat           = $request->vat;
        $buying_price  = $request->buying_price;
        $selling_price = $request->selling_price;
        $total_price   = $buying_price+($buying_price*$vat/100);
        $profit        = $selling_price-$total_price;

        $product = Products::findOrFail($id);
        $product = Products::update([
            'product_name'          => $request->product_name,
            'buying_price'          => $request->buying_price,
            'selling_price'         => $request->selling_price,
            'vat'                   => $request->vat,
            'total_price'           => $total_price,
            'profit'                => $profit,
            ]);
       return redirect("Product/{$product->id}");

      /*  Basic update system but this does not update the total_price and profit column
          $input = $request->all();
          $product = Products::findOrFail($id);
          $product->update($input);
          return redirect("Product/{$product->id}"); */
     }
```

Comment: There's no error messages here, so this question is plainly missing an [mcve]. It's probably too broad anyway, so should be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this ...

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
   $vat           = $request->vat;
   $buying_price  = $request->buying_price;
   $selling_price = $request->selling_price;
   $total_price   = $buying_price+($buying_price*$vat/100);
   $profit        = $selling_price-$total_price;

   $product = Products::findOrFail($id);
   $product->product_name            = $request->product_name;
   $product->product_category_id     = $request->product_category_id;
   $product->product_type_id         = $request->product_type_id;
   $product->product_description     = $request->product_description;
   $product->product_weight          = $request->product_weight;
   $product->buying_price            = $request->buying_price;
   $product->selling_price           = $request->selling_price;
   $product->vat                     = $request->vat;
   $product->total_price             = $total_price;
   $product->profit                  = $profit;
   $product->in_stock                = $request->in_stock;
   $updated_product = $product->save();

   if(isset($updated_product) && $updated_product != '') {
      return redirect("Product/".$id);
   }
}
```

Comment: i get some error message **syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)**
the line `$product->product_name   =>$request->product_name;` throws a Fatal error exception @YLS

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {   
    $vat           = $request->vat;
    $buying_price  = $request->buying_price;
    $selling_price = $request->selling_price;
    $total_price   = $buying_price+($buying_price*$vat/100);
    $profit        = $selling_price-$total_price;

    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
    $product->product_name = $request->product_name;
    $product->buying_price = $request->buying_price;
    $product->selling_price = $request->selling_price;
    $product->vat = $request->vat;
    $product->total_price = $total_price;
    $product->profit = $profit;
    $product->save();

   return redirect("Product/{$product->id}");

  /*  Basic update system but this does not update the total_price and profit column
      $input = $request->all();
      $product = Products::findOrFail($id);
      $product->update($input);
      return redirect("Product/{$product->id}"); */
 }
```